# Fetch featured product only from product table in Api

Tags: php, mysql, api, codeigniter

Product Table
[image]

where i want to fetch only featured product. I have defined a column in database product_type in which four types of products(hot deals, newly listed, deals of the day and featured product)**strong text** can be listed which is optional.

Blockquote

```
   Here is my model|query code in codeigniter
    

 public function featured_product()
 {
    $arrResult = array();
    
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('product');
    $this->db->where("product_type","featured");
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        $arrResult['result'] = $result;
    }
    else
    {
        $arrResult['result'] = '';
    }
    return $arrResult ;
  }
```

When i try to fetch whole product list in api i get the result but i want to show only featured product.

Comment: If its not to late, change the database design so you dont use comma delimited lists in a database column. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Hey @RiggsFolly thanks for suggestions i will do that i mean modify the database but for knowledge prospects can we use the way i have defined above. my code is wrong here?. If my code is wrong  what should be the solution in this way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I have changed my database to separate table with product_id matching with product_type. Still I find the solution to my question with a function `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Here is my updated modal query:

```
public function featured_product()
{
    $arrResponse = array();
    $data = 'featured';
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('find_in_set("'.$data.'", product_type) <> 0');
    $this->db->from('product');
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        $arrResponse['result'] = $result;
    }
    else
    {
        $arrResponse['result'] = '';
    }
    return $arrResponse ;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use `find_in_set`:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

I don’t know codeigniter, but I think, this looks useful:

https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-71337.html

Comment: Hey @akrys your post helped me with the function i don't know FIND_IN_SET() which work fine in my code

Answer (score 1):

I propose a different approach.

This is not an answer to your question, but I hope it will allow you to rethink your table structure.

Instead of storing all the `product_types` in a single column use a [pivot table](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot) (also known as a junction table).

You'll want to store all the data that you currently have in `product_types` column in a separate table(the pivot, lets call it `product_to_type`) and reference the `id` of `product_table` and `product_type` in the pivot table.

Something like this:

[image]

**Here's a nice [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9fGQkePivLnUDSDeySDqrs/0) to play around with if you want.**

This has multiple advantages:

- You have a [atomic tables](https://databasedesign-resource.com/atomic-database-values.html)
- You can add data to either table without causing trouble in other tables
- Foreign key ensure data consistency(you can probably do a better job with that. The keys are used are decent but not great)
- You can extract any sort of data with the correct use of joins
- You can add indexes to make the query buttery smooth

I'm sure there are other advantages too.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei I have done that with a separate table.